# using local mutex in a signal handler function to synchronize shared data

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, signals, posix

I have 4 `pthread`s in my application on Linux OS.

`SIGTERM` is blocked in 3 threads and only one thread handles in a signal handler function. I think the below code is safe as mutex is created locally in the signal handler function and primarily used only to push the change to shared data variable to another thread which needs to do something based on that.

Is my understanding correct?

```
void sig_handler_sigterm()
{
    mutex * m = new mutex;
    mutex_lock(m);
    //update shared data, the change needs to reflect in another thread
    mutex_unlock(m)
    sleep(2);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: A local mutex is pointless. A mutex is only useful if *more than one thread* locks/unlocks it.

Comment: Nor is it safe to call `exit()` from within a signal hander.  It's not async-signal-safe.

Comment: Is is true that mutex lock/unlock funcitons will ensure acquire/release of memory, thereby the shared data gets pushed to other threads?

Comment: @medicine28 No it's not true. mutexes are used to ensure only one thread accesses shared data at the same time. But that only works if all threads that access the shared data lock/unlock the **same** mutex. Which is not what you are doing.

Comment: 1) that's an invalid signature for a sig handler, 2) `new` isn't AS-safe, 3) `exit()` isn't AS-safe. Now even if you made the mutex static and only shared with the other thread, `mutex_{lock,unlock}` isn't AS-safe, strictly speaking (although I don't see what problems it could cause under these constraints).

Answer (score 0):

No. First of all, this is not how mutexes work. Two threads must share a mutex and both must lock it. So it can't be a local variable. Next thing is that it is safe to call only a [subset of standard library functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)subset of standard library functions from signal. brk() which can be used by new internals is not one of them. So it is not a good idea to allocate memory in signal.

Next point is that sleeping a second does not guarantee that other threads will have enough time to do what they need to do.